# How to Train on a small dataset (Fine tuning vgg16 VS small model)

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I  am trying to build a classifier to distinguish between 3 classes (palm, fist, and other). I have a small dataset so I am using augmentation. The collected data set without augmentation had ( 914, 887, 983) samples respectively. After augmentation (5481,4752, 4081) samples. I used [image-aug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) to get the augmented images.

I followed "[Building powerful image classification models using very little data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)" tutorial from Keras, but the model is over-fitting, how can i solve this?

I am using Adam optimizer with small learning rate (lr=1e-5). And only freeze the first 15 layers instead of 25.
[image]

--Edit--

small model with gradual drop out.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(img_height, img_width,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nClasses, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Result isn't good. This model is doing very well on the test set 97%, although the test and validation set are from the same distribution.

[image]

[image: [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGqeG.png]

I tried Adam with low learning rate on a smaller network

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(img_height, img_width,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nClasses, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-6),#optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And the results seems to be better. But still the training is overfitting. I think this is a good start, no need to use complicated network.
[image]

Comment: It would be hard to pinpoint the issue without additional details about nature of dataset and classes and also approx number of instances belonging to each class.

Comment: @rajat I updated the question

Comment: VGG16 is probably too powerful for this.... make a smaller model.

Comment: Try using L1/L2 regularization, thats not being used in example you refer. Also be cautious if you are using same preprocessing at both test and train time

Comment: i tried to add weight regularization at the top layer, but same results, overfitting. And yes i am using the same ImageDataGenerator.

Comment: @DanielMöller I updated the Question.

Comment: Is seems that your small model was a little better than the VGG.... perhaps even smaller?

Comment: @DanielMöller Why do you see the small model is doing better?. I am retraining now on the small model after adding drop out on the lower layers. I think that the information from the images are redundant because of the augmentation so i hope this gradual drop out idea will help.

Comment: I updated the question with the recent result. Also, i am retraining on a smaller network.

Comment: I have these two ideas (vgg fine tuning, and small network) with the results shown in the question, which one i should i proceed with?